# Executing mysql from command line just listing overview of arguments/variables

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

in XAMPP on OS X, I've set my environment path in ~/.profile, so that I can use `mysql` from the command line. This seems to work fine, as typing `mysql` launches the `mysql` CLI. However when I try to execute a database import from a file, I just get all the mysql options listed. I've not had this issue before - anyone any idea what might be the issue?

E.g

```
mysql -h localhost -u my_db_usr -p password my_db < db.sql 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.44, for apple-darwin8.11.1 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright 2000-2008 MySQL AB, 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL license
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent)
  --character-sets-dir=name 
                      Directory where character sets are.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                      with --comments
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit
  --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
  -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --default-character-set=name 
                      Set the default character set.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file)
  -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an sql error.
  -G, --named-commands 
                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                      internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                      named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                      otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                      Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                      disabled by default.
  -g, --no-named-commands 
                      Named commands are disabled. Use \* form only, or use
                      named commands only in the beginning of a line ending
                      with a semicolon (;) Since version 10.9 the client now
                      starts with this option ENABLED by default! Disable with
                      '-G'. Long format commands still work from the first
                      line. WARNING: option deprecated; use
                      --disable-named-commands instead.
  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
  --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
  -X, --xml           Produce XML output
  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
  -L, --skip-line-numbers 
                      Don't write line number for errors.
  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
  --column-names      Write column names in results.
  -N, --skip-column-names 
                      Don't write column names in results.
  -O, --set-variable=name 
                      Change the value of a variable. Please note that this
                      option is deprecated; you can set variables directly with
                      --variable-name=value.
  --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C)
  -o, --one-database  Only update the default database. This is useful for
                      skipping updates to other database in the update log.
  --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you don't supply an
                      option the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
                      PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
                      etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
                      work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
                      option is disabled by default.
  --no-pager          Disable pager and print to stdout. See interactive help
                      (\h) also. WARNING: option deprecated; use
                      --disable-pager instead.
  -p, --password[=name] 
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.
  --protocol=name     The protocol of connection (tcp,socket,pipe,memory).
  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
                      down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
                      history file.
  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
                      --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.
  -S, --socket=name   Socket file to use for connection.
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
  --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
                      also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
                      --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
  --no-tee            Disable outfile. See interactive help (\h) also. WARNING:
                      option deprecated; use --disable-tee instead
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect_timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
  --max_allowed_packet=# 
                      Max packet length to send to, or receive from server
  --net_buffer_length=# 
                      Buffer for TCP/IP and socket communication
  --select_limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates
  --max_join_size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
                      --safe-updates
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol
  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults    Print the program argument list and exit
--no-defaults       Don't read default options from any options file
--defaults-file=#   Only read default options from the given file #
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- -----------------------------
auto-rehash                       FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             latin1
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              localhost
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              3306
prompt                            mysql> 
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         FALSE
socket                            /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
table                             FALSE
user                              magento_db
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect_timeout                   0
max_allowed_packet                16777216
net_buffer_length                 16384
select_limit                      1000
max_join_size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
```

Comment: Try omitting the password value from the command so it prompts you for it ie. `mysql -h localhost -u username -p dbname < dbfile.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting the password value from the command so it prompts you for it ie.

`mysql -h localhost -u username -p dbname < dbfile.sql`

If you supply a apassword directly i have always seen it done either without whitespace like `-pthepassword` or in long opt form `--password=thepassword`

Comment: Thanks - working now. Thing is, I didn't have a space between -p and the password initially, I tried with and without the space and got the same result. Strange - but, sorted now :)

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [mysql Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html) (emphasis added):

> - [`--password[=password]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password), `-p[password]`
>
>   The password to use when connecting to the server.  **If you use the short option form (`-p`), you *cannot* have a space between the option and the password.** If you omit the ***`password`*** value following the [`--password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) or `-p` option on the command line, [**mysql**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) prompts for one.
>
>   Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. See [Section 6.1.2.1, “End-User Guidelines for Password Security”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/password-security-user.html). You can use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line.

Comment: Also, thanks - as commented above to prodigitalson, I didn't have a space between -p and the password initially. but working as per your suggestion